# yum install expat-devel failure

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, yum, apache2.4

**I'm trying to install apache v2.4.29** . 
This is my configure options :

> pcre installed 
>   ./configure --with-included-apr

There is my fatal error screen-shot.

[image: There is my fatal error screen-shot.]

I found something to fix that:
https://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=54952

But yums repos expat-devel is not enabled. I didn't find anything about fix.

```
sudo yum install expat-devel
```

[image: sudo yum install expat-devel]

Comment: Seems the yum is not able to resolve the hostname in the repo ... Do you need a proxy to access the internet ? Are the repos in an intranet ? Did you try what the error asked you to do (list all repos and try to enable one) ??

Comment: Ubuntu has `yum` ? Use `apt`.

Comment: @Exception_al No, i dont need to access the internet and Repos are not in an intranet.
"sudo yum repolist all " response is "repolist: 0"

Comment: You have no repos enabled... Look in `/etc/yum.repos.d` open the files and they should have a line saying `enabled=0` change that `0` to a `1`  You want the 'Base' repo.